# react-google-login is deprecated

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, react-google-login

I'm making a react application, in which I have used @react-oauth/google for login while for logout I thought of using GoogleLogout from react-google-login but I can see that this package is deprecated.
What can be an alternative solution to log out of google in my react app?

Answer (score 1):

You could use https://authjs.dev, it has support for many OAuth Providers.